# Return country name from a city one?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Guys is there a way on page load grab a city name from URL and then some how return the country it belongs to?

Lets say here is my URL: **site.com/sevilla_r**

How can I return España on page load and show it in the page content?

P.S

If it's a country then do nothing!

Comment: Yes. You will have to access `sevilla` from URL and then make an API call. There on server, you will have a map of Country-City, which will return Country, and Ta-Da!!! task done

Comment: buddy could you please give me some pointers I am really bad at js

Comment: are u passing city name after url @letsforum

Comment: Yes buddy city?

Comment: I just did. 1. **Access value/params from URL**. 2. **How to make an API call**. 3. **How to create a map in PHP** 4. **How to loop over list and find value**. Also, this is your first post, hence people are not downvoting, but this is a very basic question and you need to me more specific about problem.

Comment: You shuld implement a public web-service like this http://www.geonames.org/ to do that

Comment: I would like to call Goggle to get the country!

Comment: Is there any tutorial on this?

Comment: What list are you talking about where can I get one?

Comment: I can't use my own list of cities case the URL value can be god know what. I would like to call google an let it return city?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Are there only guys here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google geocade API

[Read here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

For e.g. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This will return Country name, postal code, lat lng etc

**--EDIT--**

This is how i implemented it

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=shimla&key=';

$json = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: I see this might work gonna give it a try thanks so much love you.

Comment: Please one more thing? It returns a bunch of stuff and in EN how to show the results in ES and how to retreat country from that mess?

Comment: Thanks buddy. The biggest issue I see here is that same city can be in many countries what do you recommend about that?

Comment: I am gonna share some URL please don't ban me for that: http://www.amigote.com/buscar-pareja/madrid_r I wanna show España

Comment: add this param in url to select language  "&language=ES"

Comment: But what if a city is in colombia not in españa

Comment: Is there a way to check for all countries that might contain that city?

Comment: ya u will get result of all countries

Comment: How to get for all countries?

Comment: if city is in more than one country then it will return result in different objects

Comment: but u need to select one or give user a dropdown to select one manually .  am I getting you right :p

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with cities that are in US and Spain like Toledo!

Comment: I am getting result https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Toledo&key=

Comment: oh try this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Toledo+spain&key= but it will need country name lol :D

Comment: Thanks but then I will miss the fast that it's in US too? Not sure how to work around this?

Comment: Where do I place this?

Comment: Check the Places API: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: how to implement this r&d